# php multiple values in a field and submit each value as row

Tags: php

Please help.  I know this is simple but I have been at it and cannot get it right.

I have a form with a field where the user can select multiple values.  The values are separated by a comma.

I want to submit the form, and insert individual rows for each value in the field.

I am able to explode the values in the string, by the "," and end up with each individual value; but I cannot get the SQL to insert for each value.

Example:
User selects three values: A,B,C
I can explode and echo three values, A then B Then C
I want the form to submit the fields three values as row 1 field.value = A row 2 field.value = B row 3 field.value = C.

(the user is filling out a form for taking leave.  They select multiple dates and I want one record for each date in the field, the dates are separated by commas)

```
$dates = (explode(",",$str));

foreach ($dates as $value) {
    $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_test (Date) VALUES ($value)";
}
```

any help would be so appreciated!
thank you

Comment: What happen on the DB? Which values are being added?

Comment: did you check the type? ensure that you're trying to save on the correct type, let's say, DDBB expects an integer and your values are int.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you have multiple value to submit.

```
<form action="anything">
<input type="text" name="param[]" value="A">
<input type="text" name="param[]" value="B">
<input type="text" name="param[]" value="C">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

in php

```
$data = $_POST["param"];
if(!empty($data)){
 for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    $data[$i]; // here is A,B,C
    //Your Query to insert 
 }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solutions is that it isn't flexible, here you've the hardcoded values and you're limiting the number of values.

Comment: its form you can enter any data in input tag.
i have given A, B, C for example

Comment: But it's not as flexible as adding dynamic inputs (js), split by commas. In this case, you have to add inputs one by one.

Comment: i have given example son for value with multiple param you can do it js without creating string {'params': ['A','B', 'B']}

Comment: creating a string with comma and splitting its very costly son.

Comment: Thank you so much!  So the answer (FOR MY SITUATION) is Prashant's answer.  (BUT NOT THE FORM PART, THE PHP PART).

Comment: I have a form, The employee can fill out the type of leave, begin time, end time etc.  But I wanted to be able to submit the same data, but for multiple dates.  So example, the employee wants Monday - Friday OFF.  He/she selects:  TYPE= PAID VACATION, Begin=0800, END=1700, etc, but can select DATE=day1, day2, day3, day4, day5 and submit.  with Prashant's answer it worked for me it inserted five different records, one for each day as mentioned above.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are preparing your query but you don't seem submitting it.. try this

```
$dates = (explode(",",$str)); 
foreach ($dates as $value)
 { $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_test (Date) VALUES ('$value')";
    mysqli_query(your_db_connection_object, $insertSQL);
 }
```

Comment: If you want one query and submit it for all SQLs you can append it with `$dates = (explode(",",$str)); 
foreach ($dates as $value)
{
 $insertSQL .= "INSERT INTO tbl_test (Date) VALUES ('$value');";

}
mysqli_query(your_db_connection_object, $insertSQL);`

Comment: be aware that this implementation is not sql save and can be used for SQL injection. please sanitize your input e.g. by checken oder mysql_escape... functions.